# How to detect edges of a colored photo?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm trying to implement the blind deconvolution algorithm example from Mathworks' site and when making edge detection I'm having problems because you can't use edge detection functions with RGB photos. So I converted the photo to YUV but after this I don't know in what order I should do processes and I don't even know if I am using the right method.

I applied the edge() function for all three (y,u,v) then I used YUV to RGB method to combine them again. It didn't work, I can't obtain the final WEIGHT value.

My code is below and an example link is at http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/deblurring-with-the-blind-deconvolution-algorithm.html.

```
Img = imread('image.tif');
PSF = fspecial('motion',13,45); 
Blurred = imfilter(Img,PSF,'circ','conv'); 
INITPSF = ones(size(PSF));
[J P] = deconvblind(Blurred,INITPSF,30);

%   RGB to YUV
R=Img(:,:,1); G=Img(:,:,2); B=Img(:,:,3);
Y=round((R+2*G+B)/4);
U=R-G;
V=B-G;

% finding edges for Y,U,V
WEIGHT1 = edge(Y,'sobel',.28);
se1 = strel('disk',1);
se2 = strel('line',13,45);
WEIGHT1 = ~imdilate(WEIGHT1,[se1 se2]);
WEIGHT1 = padarray(WEIGHT1(2:end-1,2:end-1),[1 1]);

WEIGHT2 = edge(U,'sobel',.28);
se1 = strel('disk',1);
se2 = strel('line',13,45);
WEIGHT2 = ~imdilate(WEIGHT2,[se1 se2]);
WEIGHT2 = padarray(WEIGHT2(2:end-1,2:end-1),[1 1]);

WEIGHT3  = edge(V,'sobel',.28);
se1 = strel('disk',1);
se2 = strel('line',13,45);
WEIGHT3 = ~imdilate(WEIGHT3,[se1 se2]);
WEIGHT3 = padarray(WEIGHT3(2:end-1,2:end-1),[1 1]);


% YUV to RGB again
G=round((WEIGHT1-(WEIGHT2+WEIGHT3)/4));
R=WEIGHT2+G;
B=WEIGHT3+G;
WEIGHT(:,:,1)=G; WEIGHT(:,:,2)=R; WEIGHT(:,:,3)=B;

P1 = P;
P1(find(P1 < 0.01))= 0;

[J2 P2] = deconvblind(Blurred,P1,50,[],double(WEIGHT));
figure, imshow(J2)
title('Newly Deblurred Image');
figure, imshow(P2,[],'InitialMagnification','fit')
title('Newly Reconstructed PSF')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll not get into the `deconvblind` de-blurring here, but let me show you how edge detection for color images can work.

```
% load an image
I = imread('peppers.png');
```

[image: original peppers image]

```
% note that this is a RGB image. 
e = edge(I, 'sobel');
```

will fail, because edge wants a 2D image, and an RGB or a YUV image is 3D, in the sense that the third dimension is the color channel.

There are a few ways of fixing this. One is to convert the image to grayscale, using

```
gray = rgb2gray(I);
```

This can then be passed into edge, to return edges based on the gray level intensities in '`gray`'.

```
e = edge(gray,'sobel'); % also try with different thresholds for sobel.
```

[image: edge computed using grayscale]

If you are really interested in the edge information in each channel, you could simply pass in the individual channels into edge separately. For example,

```
eRed = edge(I(:,:,1), 'sobel'); % edges only in the I(:,:,1): red channel.
eGreen = edge(I(:,:,2), 'sobel');
eBlue = edge(I(:,:,3), 'sobel');
```

and then based on how each of these `eRed`, `eGreen` and `eBlue` look, you could potentially combine then using the logical 'or', such that the result is an edge if any of the channels independently think it is an edge.

```
eCombined = eRed | eGreen | eBlue;
```

[image: edge computed with independent RGB channels]

What you did originally is probably unintended, as the YUV colorspace can distort the sense of edges. An edge in the R plane may not be an edge in the Y, U or V plane, and hence you'd need to make sure to use the right colorspace to detect edges, so that you can combine them after, like shown with the RGB colorspace earlier.

Comment: thanks a lot.Im very beginner for image processing.I need this for a school project and I have very limited time to fully comprehend everything so I need to run code urgently.the eRed, eBlue ... part is what exactly I need I found eCombined but in the next function Im getting "eCombined has to have size of the input image." error.How Im gonna equalize their size.image is <300x400x3 uint8> and  eCombined is <300x400 logical>.and the next function, [J2 P2] = deconvblind(Blurred,P1,50,[],double(WEIGHT));

Comment: The best way to do that is probably to use repmat: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html. Something like out = repmat(eCombined,[1 1 3]); . You may also run into data type problems, in which case, you could use im2double (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html), for example.

Comment: Apologies but I'm a little confused about why you are performing a dilation with a disk followed by a line. I do think your edge image prior to those operations are correct. Also, I'm not entirely sure why you are doing the deconvblind operation twice.

Answer (score 0):

The final form of code is below,

```
Img = imread('image.tif');
PSF = fspecial('motion',13,45);
Blurred = imfilter(Img,PSF,'circ','conv');
INITPSF = ones(size(PSF));
[J P] = deconvblind(Blurred,INITPSF,30);

eRed = edge(Img(:,:,1), 'sobel');
eGreen = edge(Img(:,:,2), 'sobel');
eBlue = edge(Img(:,:,3), 'sobel');
WEIGHT = eRed | eGreen | eBlue;
se1 = strel('disk',1);
se2 = strel('line',13,45);
WEIGHT = ~imdilate(WEIGHT,[se1 se2]);
WEIGHT = padarray(WEIGHT(2:end-1,2:end-1),[1 1]);
figure
imshow(WEIGHT)
title('Weight Array')

P1 = P;
P1(find(P1 < 0.01))= 0;

WEIGHT2 = repmat(WEIGHT,[1 1 3]);
WEIGHT3 = im2double(WEIGHT2);

[J2 P2] = deconvblind(Blurred,P1,50,[],WEIGHT3);
figure, imshow(J2)
title('Newly Deblurred Image');
figure, imshow(P2,[],'InitialMagnification','fit')
title('Newly Reconstructed PSF')
```

I can't post images yet.so I'm giving link of outputs.The last output, newly restored, has problem as I have indicated at the title of photo.I guess, still there's a data type problem.
Output link https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRTKu.jpg